# getting "Invalid DN syntax" Error while creating a new LDAP user with ruby ldap

Tags: ruby, ldap

When I try to create a new LDAP user with ruby 1.9.2 and the ruby-ldap gem (http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/) I always get this error:
"Invalid DN syntax"

I can't figure out, why this happens.
The connection to my server works fine. Reading attribues of existing users is possible without any problems.

```
cn = "#{first_name}#{last_name}"

  entry = [
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD,'objectclass',['top','person', 'user']),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'name',  [cn]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'accountExpires',  ["0"]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'displayName',  [cn]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'name',  [cn]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'givenName',  [first_name]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'sn',  [last_name]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'userPrincipalName',  ["#{first_name}.#{last_name}@my.domain"]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'pwdLastSet', ["0"]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'sAMAccountName',  ["#{first_name}.#{last_name}"]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD | LDAP::LDAP_MOD_BVALUES, 'unicodePwd',  [password_hash]),
    LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'userAccountControl',  ["66048"]),
  ]

  begin
    ldap_connection.add("cn=#{cn}, ou=MyUsers, dc=my, dc=domain", entry)
  rescue
    puts ldap_connection.err2string(ldap_connection.err)
  end
```

This happens for example with the first name "John" and the last name "Doe"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Validate that the entry can be added using a known good method: `ldapmodify`. Create a file containing [LDIF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) and add it using `ldapmodify`. The LDIF should look like:

```
dn: cn=<the cn>,ou=myusers,dc=my,dc=domain
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: user
accountExpires: 0
cn: <the cn>
name: <the cn>
... (the rest of the attributes)
```

To add using `ldapmodify`:

```
ldapmodify -h hostname -p port -c -a -f <the-file-containing-ldif> \
   -D distinguished-name -w password
```

The `distinguished-name` should be the authorization ID used in the LDAP client. If this command succeeds, the LDAP client can be sure the server is correctly set up and that the authorization ID has access rights sufficient to add that entry at that place in the directory information tree.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Using ldapmodify](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/)

Comment: Thanks, that was a great help :)
Now I was able to figure out, that the problem belongs to these 2 lines:

        `LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD | LDAP::LDAP_MOD_BVALUES, 'unicodePwd',  [password_hash]),
        LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_ADD, 'userAccountControl',  ["66048"]),`

If only one of these 2 lines is in my code, the error appears